# continue ProgressDialog until onPostExecute finishes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I know that progress dialog will stop spinning if it's not terminated immediately inside `onPostExecute()`. However, I have some methods to call inside `onPostExecute()` and I cannot transfer them to `doInBackground()` because these methods should run on UI. Is there a possible way to continue the `progressDialog` after calling these methods without stopping it to spin?

Here is the `onPostExecute` of my `AsyncTask`:

```
protected String doInBackground(final String... strings) {
//Network activity here
    }

protected void onPostExecute(String unused){  
//progressdialog stops spinning here, cannot change the message also
try {
            if(response.equals("HOST ERROR") || response.equals("CONNECTION ERROR") ||  response.equals("ERROR")){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Error").setMessage("Cannot connect to the internet.").setNeutralButton("Close", null).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete).show();
        }
            else{
                doc = Jsoup.parse(response);
                Intent cc = new Intent(activity,com.sblive.aufschoolbliz.GradeBook.class);
                subjectCodes = getSubjectCodes(); //this parsing method should run on UI
                professors = getProfs(); //this parsing  method should run on UI
                grades = getGrades(); //this parsing  method should run on UI
                cc.putExtra("subjectCodes", subjectCodes);
                cc.putExtra("professors", professors);
                cc.putExtra("grades", grades);

                if(this.pd.isShowing()) {
                    this.pd.dismiss();
                }
                context.startActivity(cc);
            }
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: if im going to transfer those parsing methods to doInBackground() and use activity.runOnUIThread, how will I wait for my network activity to finish first and execute these methods?

Comment: If these methods are taking long time that you can see the progress bar blocked, then you should consider implementing them using another AsyncTask (with another progress bar). Migrate the part that needs to be executed on UI thread to the new AsyncTask's onPostExecute()

Answer (score 1):

**<<< EDIT: >>>**

Ok forget about what I posted, silly me. Of course anything that modifies user interface needs to be called/dismissed on the UI thread.

So what I would do is run everything possible during doInBackground(), and creating/dissmissing the dialog or anything that requires to be run on the UI thread explicitly like this:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    /*Code required to run on UI thread*/  }
});
```

And im afraid that's as much as you can do without overdoing way too much.

Comment: I tried to put this inside the doInBackground and im getting an exception: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Yes you cannot call it inside the asyncTask thread. Try to call it before on the UI thread. Start it and dismiss it both on the UI thread. 
Try using the on onPreExecute() callback of the AsyncTask, I believe it is called on the UI thread. Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't get it.. I tried to put it now inside the onPreExecute() but gives me the same error

Comment: I would put all your code into doInBackground() and the parts that require UI thread within that snippet. You can call runOnUiThread as many times as you want.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it is not possible to create/dismiss a view outside of its UI thread. What you could do if you want that spinning to be flawless so bad, is to create a custom activity with that progress dialog layout, then use overridePendingTransition(0,0) in onPause() callback to prevent zoom-out animation after finish(), and use intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); for the calling intent.

Once the activty is all set jst call and dismiss it in onPreExecute() and onPostExecute(). Now you should be allowed to do that since creatin an activity is not dependant of any context.

Comment: Hope that helps you, rate my answer if at least I gave you an idea or 2!
If you have more questions or doubt i will be checking back.